# Running an Oracle report outside of Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracleforms, oraclereports

I was wondering if it were possible to run generate an oracle report by either calling it through a browser URL or generate it from a PL/SQL package rather then calling it from Oracle Forms.

We are coming away from Oracle forms and currently have all our UI in the broswer which calls PL/SQL JSON API's. This was a pretty big project but we have a gap which is generating our reports. In the long term we are going to look at new products but in the short term is it possible to generate a report outside of Oracle Forms.

Any help or direction provided would be great.

Thanks

Comment: APEX is the official Oracle solution.  Comes with newer db versions.

Comment: Yeah but we haven't gone with APEX. We've built our own front end and plsql api's. Hopefully we can still generate the report though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to generate Reports through the Oracle Reports Servlet. It allows you to generate a report directly from your browser. For example: `http://your_webserver.domain_name:port/alias/rwservlet?report=myreport.rdf&userid=
username/password@my_db&server=server_name&desformat=html&destype=cache`

Check your Fusion Middleware installation, `rwservlet` is probably already there.

[More documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/bi.1111/b32121/pbr_run.htm#RSPUB0018)